# Losing records when unwind results of lookup operation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I got a looong query on my "booking" table and it works great except when I ask for the agent.

We got one "users" table.  This table contains users, admins, agents etc..

The "booking" always have a "user", so that $lookup always goes well.

The "booking" SOMETIMES have an "agent", but most of the time that field is blank "". So when I do a $lookup it breaks the whole query and returns nothing.

I want to do the $lookup but ONLY if the "agent" field is not blank. 
Or find a way so if that $lookup fails, it does not break the whole query.

Left side is when there actually is an "agent" field containing a valid users._id - here we get the result

Right side is when the "agent" field is missing, contain a blank value, or contains an invalid value. - here it breaks the entire query.

[image]

Here is an example with data to try it out

```
db.getCollection('booking').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            property: "001",
            checkin: {$gte: 1483596800},
            checkout: {$lte: 1583596800}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",    
            as: "users"     
        }   
    },
    { $unwind: "$users" },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "agent",
            foreignField: "_id",    
            as: "agent"     
        }   
    },
    { $unwind: "$agent"} 
])



booking Table
{
    "_id" : "AAAAA",
    "property" : "001",
    "user" : "U001",
    "agent" : "A001",
    "checkin" : 1493596800,
    "checkout" : 1494374400,
    "test" : "This one will always work"
}
{
    "_id" : "BBBBB",
    "property" : "001",
    "user" : "U001",
    "agent" : "",
    "checkin" : 1493596800,
    "checkout" : 1494374400,
    "test" : "This one has blank agent and does not work"
}
{
    "_id" : "CCCCC",
    "property" : "001",
    "user" : "U001",
    "checkin" : 1493596800,
    "checkout" : 1494374400,
    "test" : "This one has no agent and does not work"
}
{
    "_id" : "DDDDD",
    "property" : "001",
    "user" : "U001",
    "agent" : "XXXX",
    "checkin" : 1493596800,
    "checkout" : 1494374400,
    "test" : "This one has invalid agent and does not work"
}


users Table 
{
    "_id" : "U001",
    "name" : "I am USER"
}
{
    "_id" : "A001",
    "name" : "I am AGENT"
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this...    { $cond {if: {agent $ne ""}, then: {$lookup code.....} - but cant get it to work.

Comment: [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/] (read this documentation it will help you to get if done)

Comment: @ShumiGupta already did that - and the page is terrible, the examples are terrible.  { $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }  I tried that, it does not work - it wont let me put a $lookup into the true-case.

Comment: Can you try to include `{ $match : { agent: { $exists : true, $ne : "" } } }` at the beginning of your aggregation array? Like -> `[ { $match: ... }, { $lookup: ... }, { $unwind: ... } ]` It applies the rest of the aggregation if `agent` field exists & not equal to `""`

Comment: @bureaquete I tried it but now it only shows those records who have something in the "agent" field.  I need to show all records, but only $lookup if the "agent" field != "". 

    { $match : { agent: { $exists : true, $ne : "" } } },
    {
     $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "agent",
      foreignField: "_id", 
      as: "agent"  
     } 
    },
    {
     $unwind: "$agent"  
    }

Comment: I see, but what I don't understand is that how does documents with empty `agent` field matched in your `$lookup`? What problem do you get in such case? Do you have records with empty `_id` in `users` collection? How do docs with empty `agent` get included in your `$lookup` confuses me.

Comment: @bureaquete I got 100 records in `bookings` and only 5 of them have a `users._id` in the `agent` field. The 95 have an empty string `"agent" : "",` ... ohh I just saw, some of them have null or no `agent` field at all. When I do the `$lookup` for the `agent` and it fails, I dont want it to terminate the entire result (which it do now)

Comment: Even with null or `""` values in `agent` field, it shouldn't fail. There must be some other trouble I think. [Check this example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-a-join-with-lookup) of `$lookup`, null or `""` values are also used in the operation, they do not break anything. Please share the error message in your question.

Comment: @bureaquete very strange - hmm... you are right (according to the example) so I think Im gonna spend some more time and figure it out :)

Comment: If you need help here, I recommend you to add the error details in your question, otherwise good luck :)

Comment: @bureaquete - ok I did some more work, and I still cant understand this... Left side is when the booking record has a valid value in `agent` and the right side is when it has no value or if the field is missing.   I put everything in this image
[https://db.tt/9w9lRlXUTn]

Comment: I cannot access dropbox sadly, can you please post it in the question for future reference?

Comment: @bureaquete there ya go - I uploaded the image to the question

Comment: The thing is, for example when you `$unwind` a `$lookup` result, if the resulting lookup array within that object is empty, that object disappears. Can you revert back step by step and see where do you lose the data. In aggregate array, remove the last command one by one to track back the trouble. The fact that you have such a long pipeline, is the cause I think.

Comment: @bureaquete I backtrack already - it is the `agent` lookup that causes this. If I remove that lookup everything works fine.  I even tried your { $match : { agent: { $exists : true, $ne : "" } } }, but no luck.   Im not sure I understand... but if a $lookup fails, the whole pipeline should fail? (return nothing) - or how do you get it to ignore a particular $lookup? 
.

Comment: You cannot do that since `$lookup` is essentially left joining, and there is not condition in it, in your case it shouldn't break, I will check more when I arrive home, please create some reproducible scenario to test in the mean time.

Comment: @bureaquete - I will do that, I will make it as small as possible.

Comment: @bureaquete I put some data and an example for you. I hope you can figure it out :)

Comment: @bureaquete  Ok I found out why...  I removed the `{$unwind: "$agent" },`  and then it worked. So I guess if you unwind a record with 0 elements, then it will remove the record completely from the result.  If you know any work around there, please let me know.

Comment: @bureaquete GOT IT!!!  - it turns out that the `$unwind`has some parms...  especially one with the nice short name `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` which tells the unwind to KEEP all records even thou they got empty arrays.  So this did the trick:  `$unwind: { path: "$agent", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }` Thank you so much for your effort, it was your "backtrack" that made me find this solutuion :-)

Comment: I guessed so, but I wanted to test with your data, couldn't see exactly where from the command, glad that was helpful :) If you'd like I can answer with that suggestion to check unwind dropping empty results etc

Comment: @bureaquete yes please do, so I can close the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem arises when you pipe the result of `$lookup` to `$unwind` that targets the resulting field where lookup resulting array resides, the empty results of lookup operation will be dropped by unwind, where your loss of data happens. Backtrack your aggregate logic and add `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option to the guilty `$unwind` step. That will stop the loss of records during that step, thus will resolve your trouble.